# Magento 2 - Removing Tax with VAT Validation on Prices that Include Tax

Tags: magento2, tax, validation, vat

We have our catalogue set up so that prices entered in the admin include tax, for example:

£75.00 (excl tax: £62.50)

During the checkout we also allow people to enter their VAT number which removes tax from the totals.

**Expected:**

Customer pays £62.50

**Actual:**

Customer pays £75.00 still (but tax is considered £0.00)

The only way around this that I can think of is that catalog prices are entered excluding tax. Is there any way this can be done with catalog prices including tax?

Answer (score 0):

My issue is that I had Cross Border Trade enabled in **Stores > Config > Sales > Tax** - set this to "No" to fix.